# gsutl rsync: skip copying large files

Tags: rsync, gsutil

How can i skip copying files larger than say 100MB with `gsutil rsync` command? The plain rsync linux utility has `--max-size=SIZE` flag. Is there an equivalent with gsutil version? I can't find any in [their manual](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)

Comment: Have you checked this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59035602/18265570)?